# How to repackage an app that is open-source (warzone 2100) and put on software centre

Tags: software-center, updates

I have been playing warzone and noted that the version up on the software center is not up to date, so I have downloaded and installed the newer version. But let's say I wanted to update the one on ubuntu software center. How would I go about doing this.

NOTE: I do not own warzone 2100

Comment: Learn Debian packaging. http://wiki.debian.org/HowToPackageForDebian   https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MOTU

Comment: Also, you should talk with current maintainer of the package: `apt-get changelog warzone2100  | sed -n '/@/{p;q;}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already a PPA for the beta version of warzone2100, to install and use the latests unstable version of the game use these commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:littel-jo/warzone-dev
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install warzone2100
```

Other then that you can learn how to package and application and prepare for launchpad [here](http://developer.ubuntu.com/packaging/html/).